# PHP Cookies and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cookies

I'm currently trying to make a PHP call to receive a cookie set by the following chunk of code when the user first lands on a page

```
if (empty($_COOKIE["uuid"])) {
$uuid = uniqid();  // or use a real UUID
setcookie("info", $uuid, $thisAid, $thisSubID, $thisURL, time()+30*24*60*60, "/");
}
else {
$uuid = $_COOKIE["uuid"];
foreach($_COOKIE as $name => $uuid){
// you can check any conditions based on cookie name $name
$cookiequery = "INSERT INTO table_name(WebTraffic) VALUES(" . mysql_escape_string($uuid) . ##")";
mysql_query($cookiequery);
unset($cookiequery);
```

and then later to add another line to the database when the user hits a specific page to take the values from the cookie and add it to the database

```
if (isset($_COOKIE["uuid"]))
$values = '';
$sql = "    INSERT INTO WebTraffic (aid, subID, campaignID, URL, uuid) VALUES(";
foreach ($_COOKIE as $name => $uuid)
$values .= "'$uuid'";

$sql .= $values.")";
```

but neither are working, can anyone point me in the right direction? Thanks!

EDIT: The values are strings set earlier:

```
$thisAID = $_GET['aID'];
$thisSubID = $_GET['subID'];
$thisCampaignID = $_GET['campaignID'];
$thisURL = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$uuid = uniqid();
```

which are pulled from the URL passed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to look at setting a cookie in PHP correctly. the `setcookie()` function expects up to 6 parameters as follows:

```
setcookie(name,value,expire,path,domain,secure)
```

Your `setcookie()` has 7 parameters in the call and are not following the structure correctly:

```
setcookie("info", $uuid, $thisAid, $thisSubID, $thisURL, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
```

In addition you are checking for an empty cookie named 'uuid' with your code `empty($_COOKIE["uuid"])` however you are setting a cookie with the name info.

You would need to re-arrange this to be:

```
setcookie("uuid", $uuid, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
```

However I don't know what the `$thisAid`, `$thisSubID` or `$thisURL` variables contain or are for?

[W3 Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_http_setcookie.asp) have a pretty good example of `setcookie()` and there is always the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php) itself

If you would want to use the one cookie to store all of your variables and then build your SQL query then you could either set a cookie seperately for each variable as so:

```
setcookie("uuid", $uuid, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
setcookie("thisAid", $thisAid, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
setcookie("thisSubID", $thisSubID, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
setcookie("thisURL", $thisURL, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
setcookie("campaignID", $thisCampaignID, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
```

or alternatively set one cookie with a ; symbol to seperate each value as so:

```
setcookie("uuid", $thisAid . ";" . $thisSubId . ";" . $thisCampaignID. ";" . $thisURL . ";" . $uuid, time()+30*24*60*60, "/")
```

You could then use the `explode()` function to split the cookie value apart and then use a foreach loop on this to build your SQL query as below:

```
    $values = explode( ";", $_COOKIE['uuid'] );

    foreach( $values as $value ) {  $sqlValues .= $value . ","; }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO WebTraffic (aid, subID, campaignID, URL, uuid) VALUES($sqlValues);
```

Alternatively using multiple setcookie() calls above you could do it as so:

```
    $sql = "INSERT INTO WebTraffic (aid, subID, campaignID, URL, uuid) VALUES($_COOKIE['thisAid'], $_COOKIE['subID'], $_COOKIE['campaignID'], $_COOKIE['thisURL'], $_COOKIE['uuid'] );
```

One other thing to note however is you really should be using prepared statements when inserting or retrieving information from a database to avoid SQL injection attacks. Do you know what these are/are you using any prevention techniques to avoid them?

Comment: would it work better if I had setcookie("info"...) followed by six of the 7 parameters?

Comment: You are checking for a cookie with the name 'uuid' but setting a cookie with the name 'info', so you would need to name the cookie 'uuid' also. You can do just fine by putting setcookie('uuid', $uuid, time() +30*24*60*60). That would work by itself. What else is contained in the other variables ($thisAid, $thisSubID, $thisURL) and what are they for?

Comment: I'm tracking URLs for analytics with the cookies, I explained the variables a bit better in my original question

Comment: So do you need to set seperate cookies for each of these variables ($thisAid, $thisSubID, $thisURL) or keep all the values inside one cookie?

Comment: All inside one cookie, they're all in one URL

http://www.example.com/?aid=xxx&subid=xxx&campaignid=xxx

I would like it to pull the values of that string and store it in one cookie, currently I have the code to do it in the PHP before but not to save it in the cookie

Comment: Then you would have to set it like this: setcookie('uuid', $uuid . $thisAid . $thisSubID . $thisURL, time() +30*24*60*60, "/"). This will save a cookie with the name 'uuid' and the value will just be a long string of all those values. You would then access it with $_COOKIE['uuid']

Comment: Is it possible to store this in a database like I did above?

Comment: To set it in the database it would appear that you would want to set seperate cookies for each variable. However note that doing a foreach through the $_COOKIE[] array will bring up all the cookies set on the users computer for your page meaning you could end up with alot more than you anticipated. Your other option is to store the cookie with a ; symbol between each variable and then implode this to an array and do a foreach loop on this to build the sql query. For example, set it like this setcookie('uuid', $uuid . ";" . $thisAid . ";" . $thisSubID . ";" . $thisURL, time() +30*24*60*60, "/")

Comment: Can you give me a better example or point me in the right direction? I've appreciated all your help so far

Comment: Hi Samathana, I have updated my answer above as it's easier to read there... Please take a re-read and let me know if it helps at all?

Comment: I used the multiple cookie option and tested, looks like it's working better, one last question, will this work for my isset check on another page?

Comment: if you are using isset then you will have to check that each cookie is set as so: if( isset( $_COOKIE['uuid'] ) && isset( $_COOKIE['thisAid'] && isset( $_COOKIE['thisSubID'] && isset( $_COOKIE['thisURL'] && isset( $_COOKIE['campaignID'] ) ) to see if each cookie has been set on the browser or not. If this works for you can you accept the answer please :-). Try it out and let me know if you need any further help!

Comment: Also, one last thing before I go. Are you sanitizing your data? You are using GET string queries for filling data that will be used in database queries which leaves you open to SQL injection attacks. Either make sure you are santising your input correctly or use parametered queries with bound values such as PDO.

Comment: also it's a temporary solution not a final one, I'd be spending more time on it if it wasn't being implemented for less than a month :)